# What is the use of angular ui-mask?

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, angular-ui

https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask/master/demo/index.html

This is the only documentation that i could find. And it does not make much sense to me. There is no official demo available as far as i can see.

ui-mask-placeholder and ui-mask-placeholder-char do not seem to work.

When the user types some value in the masked field, the mask vanishes and the user can type any value he wants. So basically I am just left using a placeholder. Then what is the point of the ui-mask? What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ui-mask defines a input pattern and forces the user to put a value that fit with it.

For instance, with a mask set to `(999) 999-9999`, the user will ony be able to put some values as `(123) 456-7890`.

The mask definition considers these patterns:

> `A` Any letter.
>
> `9` Any number.
>
> `*` Any letter or number.
>
> `?` Make any part of the mask optional.

So, if you define a mask as `AAAAA-AAAAA`, user can only write some `hello-world` or `qwert-yuiop` as value (Only letters).

The default placeholder char is the char that is used as "fill" in the input when it's focused and the value is empty:

If you choose a mask `AAAAA-AAAAA` and a default placeholder char `_` (default), you will have `_____-_____` when you focus input field.

If you choose a default placeholder char `X`, you will have `XXXXX-XXXXX`

Comment: That is the functionality that i expected. But it doesn't seem to be working for me. Which script files have to included for this to work? And also, is there a proper demo available? Thanks. :)

Comment: You just have to include `angular.js` core file and `angular-ui-mask/dist/mask.js`. Be sure you add dependency to `ui.mask`: `angular.module('myApp', ['ui.mask'])`. About a proper demo, I don't find another one as complete as the one you link.